# How can I control output order using Low Variables and Playa

Tags: playa, parse-order, low-variables

I am trying to control the order of my products using Low Variables (2.3.4) and Playa (4.3.3).

I have a Low Variable of type Playa name lv_product_order which I use to output the ids in the following manner.

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_product_order"}{entry_id},{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

This gives me entry ids that I selected in the correct order, also including hte additional unnecessary comma.  So I tried to than include this in my channel entries loop in the following manner.

```
    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="product" 
        disable="member_data|pagination|category_fields" 
        dynamic="off" 
        fixed_order="{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_product_order"}{entry_id},{/exp:low_variables:parse}"}
```

This results in the all products being output - even though I only selected a few in the LV Playa field, and order is obviously not preserved either.  Template debugging displays the following tag output:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product" disable="member_data|pagination|category_fields" dynamic="off" fixed_order="M40o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr"}
```

Where does the following hash come from? I expect this to be a list of IDs.

> M40o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr

I have the field set to early parsing so I figured this would parse before the channel entry tag. Is this a parsing order issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Do you have this variable set to "on" for early parsing?

Comment: @LisaWess Yes, is that correct?

Comment: I haven't worked with the LVs enough to be certain; but I'd try toggling it off.  What you're seeing there is a template marker that is not being replaced in later parsing in the template.  so switching it off may give you some relief.  Also - what version of EE are you on?

Comment: @LisaWess I am using EE 2.5.3. Unfortunately turning off early parsing produces the same result.

Comment: Thomas - does this solution work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101138/passing-entry-ids-to-channelentries-tag-with-low-variables-entries-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101138/passing-entry-ids-to-channelentries-tag-with-low-variables-entries-select) has an answer from Low that should work for you.

> > Here's how: make sure early parsing is enabled for that variable, and then use the variable syntax instead of the tag syntax:
>
> ```
> {exp:channel:entries channel="groups" entry_id="{lv-home-groups}"}
> code here
> {/exp:channel:entries}
> ```

Comment: Works great, Thanks Lisa.  Only bummer was losing the multi-selection and status color features provided in Playa.  Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try an embed. In your main template put the embed code to a newly created embed template (in my example, it's 'embed_product_list').

`{embed="template-group/embed_product_list" product_ids="{lv_product_order}"}`

Then in the embed_product_list template, your opening tag would be:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="product" 
    disable="member_data|pagination|category_fields" 
    dynamic="no" 
    fixed_order="{embed:product_ids}"}
```

Comment: I thought Low Variables was often used to reduce performance issues with embeds.  Won't this create an issue?

Comment: Also, this is not working, I have tried to implement, yet the value that is passed into the fixed_order parameter from the playa field is an array containing the id number as well as the url title and the title.